# How to permanently add a route in OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, static-routes

I have a Mac Pro and the problem is that it is not connecting to systems in other VLANs.
This can be temporarily  archived by

```
sudo route -n add -net <IP>/mask  <Gateway>
```

However it vanishes in the next laptop restart. How can I add the route permanently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307221/add-a-permanent-static-route-in-high-sierra

Answer (score 1):

I myself didn't manage to make it work with the solution that pabo provided.
I ended up running it in the crontab:

`env EDITOR=nano crontab -e`

add the script line:

`@reboot sh /path/to/your/script.sh`

make sure that if you need sudo rights, you would need to disable password for sudo use for your script. More info here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264663/shutdown-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified

Additionally, if you are using some build in commands in mac, like for example `route` you need to specify full path of the binary file. Here is example of `script.sh` file:

`sudo /sbin/route add 192.168.64.0/16 192.168.100.1`

Answer (score 0):

Found [an article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060329085850170) which suggests adding something like this

```
ifconfig en2 inet 11.22.33.5 netmask 255.255.255.252
route -n add 11.22.33.64/26 111.222.333.6
```

to `/etc/rc.common`. Apparently the preceding ifconfig line is necessary, though I don't know why.

Comment: Is Command-K still a thing in macOS, the way it was in OS X? If so, you can use that, since it's a front-end *of sorts* for what you do in Terminal.